# JavaScript. Return random number from 1 to 10 not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, loops, random

So I have code where is spawning 15 items, I need to make, that after user click on any item, It will return unique number. But for now after click all items returning the same number.

```
for (var t = 0; t < 16; t++) {
    ....//PART OF CODE
    var min = 1;
    var max = 10;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    _chestArr[t].addEventListener('click',function(){
    var tezt = document.createTextNode(random);
    document.body.appendChild(tezt);
    },false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the random part that's the problem, it's the fact that the event handler functions you're creating close over the *variable* `random`, not the value it had when the individual functions were created. So they all see the last value you assign to it.

The typical way to fix this is with a builder function or `Function#bind`:

Builder function:

```
for (var t = 0; t < 16; t++) {
    ....//PART OF CODE
    var min = 1;
    var max = 10;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    _chestArr[t].addEventListener('click',buildHandler(random),false);
}
function buildHandler(r) {
    return function(){
        var tezt = document.createTextNode(r);
        document.body.appendChild(tezt);
    };
}
```

`Function#bind`:

```
for (var t = 0; t < 16; t++) {
    ....//PART OF CODE
    var min = 1;
    var max = 10;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    _chestArr[t].addEventListener('click',function(r){
    var tezt = document.createTextNode(r);
    document.body.appendChild(tezt);
    }.bind(null, random),false);
}
```

Note that the `Function#bind` option will affect the value of `this` within your handler, whereas the builder function version won't. You're not using `this` in your handler, but if you were, the builder function would probably be the way to go.